# Set-based alternative to loops in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I read many posts saying in SQL you should think in terms of sets and not in terms of loops. I am trying to do the following:

```
SELECT SUM(Score)
FROM (SELECT W.StemId, W.Weight*Q.Weight As Score
    FROM TfidfWeights AS W
    INNER JOIN Query AS Q ON W.StemId = Q.StemId
    WHERE W.DocumentId = '0054f88e-a565-4f54-866a-e6107948567e') TMP
```

How do I achieve to obtain 'Score' for every 'DocumentId' I have. In other words avoid looping through the 'Documents' table and compute the 'Score' for each document.

Comment: Have a search for "GROUP BY" online.

Comment: The generic way would be to group by and then use SUM. Depending on which specific database you use, they all have different other specialized functions that can help.

Comment: Your query is fine.  The reference to loops usually means cursors.  With a single query the optimizer will execute it in the most efficient method based on the available data and database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff his problem is that the query is fine for the specified document, but he wants to calculate the sum for all groups in one go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get sum for each DocumentID

```
SELECT W.DocumentId, SUM(W.Weight*Q.Weight) As Score
FROM TfidfWeights AS W
INNER JOIN Query AS Q ON W.StemId = Q.StemId
GROUP BY W.DocumentId
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Any books could you recommend to evolve this set based thinking? At times it is really frustrating, because the alternate solution in C# or C++ is just so simple :(

Comment: @SanjnaMalpani There are so many online tutorials available for this, google "sql tutorial" that may help you more :)